# HTML5 Canvas DrawImage Unspecified Error

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, html5-canvas

I am creating a HTML5 game using canvas. When playing it in IE, I am getting a "SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error" when the following code is ran.

```
ctx.drawImage(
    this.img, 
    this.startX + (column*this.width), 
    this.startY + (row*this.height), 
    this.width, 
    this.height, 
    posX, 
    posY, 
    width, 
    height
);
```

This error is occurring at the end of the game with the same image. There are other images using the exact same code throughout the whole game, but they don't get the error. Any suggestions on what could be causing this error?

Update:

This only happens in IE. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Here is a console.log for the variables when it crashes.

```
this.img.complete :true
this.startX :0
column :0
this.startX + (column*this.width) :00
this.startY :0
row :0
this.startY + (row*this.height) :00
this.width :1200
this.height :1200
posX :204
posY :68
width :612
height :612
```

The images are added to an object called Game.sprites. They are added in the following manner

```
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = assetDir + "Images/myImage.png";
Game.sprites.myImageAnimation = new AnimatedSpriteSheet(imageObj, 0, 0, 1200, 1200, 5, 24);
//function AnimatedSpriteSheet(img, startX, startY, width, height, imagesPerRow, imageCount)
```

The spritesheet that is crashing is 1,174 KB in size. It is the largest file in the game. I also tried removing that sprite from the game, but the next image from the game also crashed it. That image was only 280 KB in size.

Comment: Try to `console.log()` every arguments before calling this and post it here

Comment: what's the distinction between this.width and this.height used through out the line and then the values of width and height at the end of the line?

Comment: Your image, is loaded properly, with method "onload"?

Comment: Is this only happening in IE, does it work in other browsers?

Comment: @CodeUniquely Uniquely: this.width and this.height refers to the size of each sprite on the sprite sheet object. width and height are parameters passed in that say how big to draw the image.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: Yes this is only happening in IE. Chrome and Firefox work fine.

Comment: @AlexNikulin: I am not using the onload function currently. All of the images are loaded at the beginning of the game in the exact same way. The image that it is crashing on is at the very end of the game, and has had time to fully load. The console.log shows that the image was "complete"

Comment: and if you omit this ctx.drawImage call, the code continues running well?

Comment: @Kaiido : Yes it continues to run if i omit the drawimage call.

Comment: @dburgener Have you tried putting a undefined check around that drawImage of the sprite you are having problems with? I am asking this because if an image isn't loaded it may fail and break, I know Chrome is fine and Firefox, but IE may handle image loading differently.

Comment: I had the same issue. In my case it was related to a problem with a hidden image's source attribute so that the browser couldn't load the image. The img node exists, so you pass a valid img object onto the drawImage() function, but it can't get the source bitmap so it crashes with the specified error.